# Spring AMQP (RabbitMQ) Throwing Channel Shutdown Error

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am trying to do `channel.basicReject()` to requeue message based on some condition by creating an MethodInterceptor `ConsumerAdvice` and adding it to SMLC `factor.setAdviceChain(new ConsumerAdvice())`. I also have concurrentConsumer configuration which is set to 10. The moment my reject condition is met I issue basicReject command and it gets redelivered and processed by another consumer. During this redelivery process I get the below error,

```
2019-11-07 17:34:13.268 ERROR 29385 --- [ 127.0.0.1:5672] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag 1, class-id=60, method-id=80)
2019-11-07 17:34:13.268 DEBUG 29385 --- [ool-2-thread-13] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Received shutdown signal for consumer tag=amq.ctag-HUaN71TZUqMfLDR7k6LwGQ

com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag 1, class-id=60, method-id=80)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:516)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:346)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:178)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:111)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:670)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:48)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:597)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My message is not getting lost but I am seeing a bunch of above errors and unable to understand why this is happening. If anyone has any clues please guide me.

Below are the trace logs,

```
2019-11-08 02:11:31.883 TRACE 8695 --- [askExecutor-138] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,99) channel.getChannelNumber()
2019-11-08 02:11:31.883  INFO 8695 --- [askExecutor-138] c.g.s.w.consumer.advice.ArgumentUtils    : Channel number before triggering redelivery : 99 
2019-11-08 02:11:31.883 TRACE 8695 --- [askExecutor-138] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,99) channel.basicReject([2, true])
2019-11-08 02:11:31.883  INFO 8695 --- [askExecutor-138] c.g.s.w.consumer.advice.ArgumentUtils    : ==============================================================================
2019-11-08 02:11:31.883  INFO 8695 --- [askExecutor-138] c.g.s.w.consumer.advice.ConsumerAdvice   : Requeue Message attempted, status : true
2019-11-08 02:11:31.884 TRACE 8695 --- [askExecutor-138] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Waiting for message from consumer.
2019-11-08 02:11:31.884 TRACE 8695 --- [askExecutor-138] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Retrieving delivery for Consumer@7783912f: tags=[[amq.ctag-eY7LN-1pSXPX8FKRBgt-ug]], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,99), conn: Proxy@37ffe4f3 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@708dfe10 [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 58638], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2019-11-08 02:11:31.884 DEBUG 8695 --- [askExecutor-138] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it

com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag 1, class-id=60, method-id=80)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.checkShutdown(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:436)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.nextMessage(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:501)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:843)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:832)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$700(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:78)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1073)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag 1, class-id=60, method-id=80)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:516)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:346)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:178)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:111)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:670)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:48)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:597)
    ... 1 common frames omitted

2019-11-08 02:11:31.884 ERROR 8695 --- [ 127.0.0.1:5672] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag 2, class-id=60, method-id=90)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to show your code and configuration.

It seems like the SMLC has its default configuration to automatically acknowledge messages and this failure is because you already rejected it; why are you interacting with the channel directly?

You can simply throw an exception and the container will reject the message on your behalf.

Comment: I will share the github project containing this error in couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will helpful for someone.

I had the same error because of invalid input data. But when I added next properties:

```
"rabbit.listener.acknowledgeMode": "MANUAL",
"rabbit.listener.defaultRequeueRejected": "true",
"rabbit.listener.prefetchCount": "1",
```

the problem stop to break my program but only had stopping my listener